# jQuery Animation issue using elastislide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having issues with my jQuery animation using **elastislide** as you can see in my **[DEMO](http://jzm.co.nz/clients/kate/index.html)**.  When you load the page all boxes bar the one on the left hand side load correctly of the clients specifications of `-25px`.  What I would like to do is have all four boxes show correctly.  I also have noted when you hover over the last box the tail disappears, this should be the same as the first box.

**Homepage jQuery:**

```
$(".es-carousel ul li").hover(function(){
     $(this).children('span').animate({left:"20px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
     $(this).children('b').animate({top:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
}, function() {
 $(this).children('span').animate({left:"20px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
     $(this).children('b').animate({top:"20px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
        <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
            <div class="es-carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14.jpg" alt="image01" /></a><span class="carousel_caption">Lorem ipsum sit amet</span><b>+</b></li>     
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Sed do eiusmod tempor</span><b>+</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Tempor ut labore</span><b>+</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Dolore magna</span><b>+</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_5.jpg" alt="image05" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Lorem ipsum sit amet</span><b>+</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_6.jpg" alt="image06" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Sed do eiusmod tempor</span><b>+</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_7.jpg" alt="image07" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Lorem ipsum sit amet</span><b>+</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/image_14_8.jpg" alt="image08" /></a> <span class="carousel_caption">Dolore magna</span><b>+</b></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Elastislide Carousel -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.es-carousel-wrapper{padding:40px 0 0 0; position:relative;clear:both;}
.es-carousel{overflow:hidden;}
.es-carousel ul{display:none; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
.es-carousel ul li{height:100%;float:left;display:block; position: relative;}
.es-carousel ul li span.carousel_caption{ position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:-25px; background:url(images/slider_caption_bg.png) no-repeat; width:190px; color: #fff; padding:5px;}
.es-carousel ul li b{ position:absolute; right:0px; top:-20px;background:url(images/slider_caption_bg.png) repeat;color: #fff; padding:3px 5px;}
.es-carousel ul li a{display:block;}
.es-carousel ul li a img{display:block;border:none;max-height:100%;max-width:100%;padding:0px; margin:0px;}
.es-nav{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem for both the first and the last boxes, is that they are going outside your div with the class **"es-carousel"** you need to play with it's width and it's padding.

looks like you can fix it by updating your css to this padding.
would that work?

```
.es-carousel-wrapper {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-left: 30px;
position: relative;
clear: both;
}

.es-carousel {
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 10px 0 25px;
}
```

Comment: Yep,  I guessed as much but I cannot work out where to place the width:; to set a width is it on a class or the div or both?

Comment: looks like there are other boxes there as well, it seems like you have 8 of them, you don't wanna show those?

Comment: Nope I have not adjusted the HTML yet.  We have stripped the slider function out "display:none"

Comment: Hey,  Check now I am still having issues with the left first box any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer with some css updates, hopefully this helps